# Difference between $(function) with multi event vs multi $(function) with single event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it big difference and what difference between this codes?

```
$(function(){
$("#id1").click(function(){ //some codes}
$("#id2").click(function(){ //some codes}
$("#id3").click(function(){ //some codes}
});
```

vs

```
$(function(){ $("#id1").click(function(){ //some codes}});
$(function(){ $("#id1").click(function(){ //some codes}});
$(function(){ $("#id1").click(function(){ //some codes}});
```

I know its document.ready() but how this notation affect the speed of page?

Comment: You're calling the DOM ready function uneccessary two extra times, it won't be noticeable, but why would you when you don't have to.

Comment: both will work but no need to multiple `document.ready`

Comment: Why does the second one have `#id1` thrice?

Comment: It is example, not real code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple calls to `document.ready` could cause your code to run a bit slower, as the jspref shows: http://jsperf.com/abusing-jquery-document-ready.

But more so, it would damage readability. (When does the code begin? which functions are first run?). I'm all for a big all-in-one `init()` function.

Answer (score 1):

By default jquery will merge all `$(function(){ ... })` calls into a singular one found in a document. When you have several DOM ready calls a.k.a `$(function(){ ... })` you require jquery to perform extra work (which takes some time, and a bit of memory).

So you should better be always using on one `DOM Ready handler`, wrapping all your stuff there - for the better performance.